# Android Progressbar not allowing to switch tab

Tags: android, listview

I have two tabs in my app.First tab displays the details of user and the second tab displays the applications that are installed on his device.I have used Package manager for getting the installed apps and it is running ins background thread. If the user clicked the second tab before the background thread completes I want to show a progressdialog.But the problem is if progressdialog is displayed on the screen user can't switch to next tab.Is there any way to solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Progress dialogue by default works in dialogue mode and freezes any operations until the progress bar is gone.

I had faced issues with controlling progress bar (though my requirements were more than yours like customizing looks and showing/ hiding/ freezing bar at will), so I ended up creating a custom progress bar.

It is pretty simple

1. Create 2 straight straight bars, one black and other of any color (if you want something more fancy, it is upto you)
2. Add the bars to drawable and then to your layout xml in hidden mode. The colored bar exactly on top (superimpose) of black bar
3. Now where you want to show the progress bar, make the black bar visible first, and adjust the width of colored bar (on top of black bar) as per the progress.

This will give you proper functionality of the progress bar.

As you are playing around only with imageviews, you have full control over when to show or hide the bar. Also by default it will not freeze the view. You can freeze at will by capturing onTouch event.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. As the requirement changed I haven't tried this solution.